# why does this error appear when I start the flaskserver with gunicorin and gevent?

Tags: python, flask, compiler-errors, gevent, flask-socketio

I'm trying to run a socketio flask server and ran into the issue above. I can't figure out where the overflow happens, despite the error message tells me. Help?!

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required, logout_user
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send
import socketio

from auth import authentication
from manager import manager
from remote import remote
from models import db, User

def create_socketserver():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = True
    #app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'nF4fN^xe=X*tBM/X+\A4A/'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///user.db'
    db.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(authentication)
    app.register_blueprint(manager)
    app.register_blueprint(remote)
    
    socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')
    
    return app, socketio


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app, socketio = create_socketserver()

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('base.html')
    
    login_manager = LoginManager(app)
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    logout_user
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Error in command line:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/server $ python __init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 647, in run
    monkey.patch_thread()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 195, in ignores
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 754, in patch_thread
    gevent_threading_mod, _ = _patch_module('threading',
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 443, in _patch_module
    gevent_module, target_module, target_module_name = _check_availability(name)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/monkey.py", line 429, in _check_availability
    gevent_module = getattr(__import__('gevent.' + name), name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 988, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 149, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 88, in acquire
  File "src/gevent/_semaphore.py", line 273, in gevent._gevent_c_semaphore.Semaphore.__enter__
  File "src/gevent/_semaphore.py", line 274, in gevent._gevent_c_semaphore.Semaphore.__enter__
  File "src/gevent/_semaphore.py", line 175, in gevent._gevent_c_semaphore.Semaphore.acquire
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/thread.py", line 121, in acquire
    acquired = BoundedSemaphore.acquire(self, blocking, timeout)
  File "src/gevent/_semaphore.py", line 175, in gevent._gevent_c_semaphore.Semaphore.acquire
  File "src/gevent/_semaphore.py", line 200, in gevent._gevent_c_semaphore.Semaphore.acquire
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

[as .png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ErVI.png)

*edit*
Hopefully this better now...
I changed the log to text now
*edit out*

Comment: Paste the error message as text.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón hopefully this helps a little bit better now

Comment: Create `app` with the simplest configuration and then start adding more configurations until it fails. Once you find out the configuration that causes the problem, you can decide if you need it or not. And if you need it, it will reduce the problem. Also include the versions of all the components involved. If you are not using the latest versions try to use them and see if that works.